# GWT RequestBuilder set client Date to HTTP Date POST header

Tags: http, gwt, date, http-request

I'm using GWT RPC to communicate between client and server. 
I want to be able to read the browser's date on the server side, and for that I'm using setRpcRequestBuilder from the class ServiceDefTarget to costumize my request, and add the header I want.

On the client side I'm using:

```
private static final RpcRequestBuilder rpcReqBuilder = new RpcRequestBuilder() {

    @Override
    protected RequestBuilder doCreate(String serviceEntryPoint) {

        RequestBuilder builder = super.doCreate(serviceEntryPoint);
        builder.setHeader("Date1", new Date().toString()); 
        return builder;

    }
};

 ......

((ServiceDefTarget) greetingService).setRpcRequestBuilder(rpcReqBuilder); 

//rpc call
greetingService.greetServer(.........)
```

On the server side I do:

```
HttpServletRequest request = this.getThreadLocalRequest();
    Enumeration<?> enumeration = request.getHeaderNames();
    while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
        String name = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
        String value = request.getHeader(name);
        System.out.println(name + ": " + value);
    }
```

which among all the default headers prints

```
Date1: Tue Apr 10 12:19:28 BST 2012
```

Ok, this works fine, but when I try to set the "Date" header, then it doesn't show up on the server side. Why is that? Anybody can help. I'll be very helpfull. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Date` is a [predefined header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.18) of HTTP, and by definition, `XMLHttpRequest` (the thing behind GWT's `RequestBuilder`) [cannot let you set it](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#dom-xmlhttprequest-setrequestheader) to an arbitrary value.

Anyway, when crafting your own headers, you should add a prefix to avoid conflicts with other things on the network adding headers, something like `MyApp-Date` or `X-MyApp-Date` (like GWT does it with `X-GWT-Permutation` and `X-GWT-Module-Base` in GWT-RPC and RequestFactory)

Comment: Thank you. That is kind of what I was thinking. 
Concerning the prefixes I'm aware of that, I'm just on "testing mode" so I'm not really paying much attention to that yet. :) Thanks for your answer and advice.